# Joining rainfall data to point features using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

I have 180 point feature classes with rainfall totals. Each feature class represents one days rainfall for a region and has around 36K points (think of each point as a weather station in the region). Each feature class only has one non-required attribute, "RAINFALL" with the total rainfall for a given day at that weather station. I need to join these features together so that the resulting feature class has a attribute column for each day. Here is my simplistic start to my code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\users\rainfall_data'
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print fcs
for fc in fcs:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    shpname = 'r_'+desc.name[:8]
    print shpname
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc,shpname,'float',4,2)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,shpname,'[RAINFALL]','VB')
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc,["RAINFALL"])
print "Merging..."
arcpy.Merge_management(fcs,r'C:\Users\rainfall_data\output.shp')
print "Done."
```

Obviously merging is not getting me the result I want. I get roughly 4 million points and a lot of 0's because it merges every record but I don't know how I can do this with spatial join.

I'm new to arcpy.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer to your question as, to be honest, I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish (a brief example or more detailed explanation of what the desired outcome is may help, or I may just be missing the point).  But, on a related note, you should carefully consider if you have to have the data in Shapefile format or if outputting the data to a file geodatabase feature class would be acceptable.  I don't know the file sizes you're getting, but there are known limits for shapefiles. http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37447

Comment: How will you decide which day's rainfall is contained within any given shapefile - is this included in the shapefile's name? Or within an attribute in the shapefile?

Comment: Stephen, it is contained in the name of the shapefile. In lines 6 and 7 of my code I'm using the describe function to get the shapefile name to be used as the newly added attribute.

Comment: John, sorry for the lack of clarity. Ultimately I need a shapefile that has 180 attributes (columns) (one for each day) with the rainfall totals at each of the weather stations (rows). I'm under the 2GB limit for shapefiles but I had that same thought.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have a unique identifier (e.g. SiteID) on your point locations that is common to all 180 shapefiles.  I suspect that this is probably the case.

I'll also assume that the Rainfall values are stored in a field with a different name for each shapefile that represents the date e.g. RainJan1, RainJan2, etc.  If not, then you may need to use the Add/Calc/DeleteField technique for renaming shapefile fields rather than [Alter Field (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000198000000) that works for geodatabases nowadays (or do this as part of TableToTable field mapping - see below).

We can then keep the first shapefile as it is and for the other 179 shapefiles do the following:

1. Use [arcpy.TableToTable_conversion](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000) to strip just the unique identifier (e.g. SiteID) and rainfall field (e.g. RainJan2) out into a two column table (e.g.RainJan2Table):

> - The Field Map parameter controls how the input fields in the Input
>     Features will be written to the Output Features.
> - To drop fields
>     during the conversion, delete input fields from the Field Map. This
>     will not affect the input feature class.

2. Use [arcpy.JoinField_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) to join the two column table (e.g.RainJan2Table) onto the first shapefile using the unique identifier (e.g. SiteID) as the join field.